Page fault directly after setting PG bit in CR0
I'm experiencing an issue in my paging code for an OS I'm working on based off BrokenThorn Entertainment's tutorial.
I'm not exactly the best at paging/memory management, but I've exhausted most of my available expertise.
When I enable paging, there's a page fault exception at the instruction afterward (the while loop in the code)
Here is the virtual memory management code (also, I have verified PMM does work):


#include "include/vmm.h" // Main header file

// Variables
pagedirectory_t *currentDirectory = 0; // Current page directory 
uint32_t currentPDBR = 0; // Current page directory base register address
}

// vmm_loadPDBR(uint32_t pdbr_addr) - Loads a new value into the PDBR address
void vmm_loadPDBR(uint32_t pdbr_addr) {
    asm ("mov %0, %%cr3" :: "r"(pdbr_addr));
}

// vmm_switchDirectory(pagedirectory_t *directory) - Changes the current page directory.



// vmm_flushTLBEntry(uint32_t addr) - Invalidate the current TLB entry
void vmm_flushTLBEntry(uint32_t addr) {
    asm volatile ("cli");
    asm volatile ("mov %0, %%eax" :: "r"(addr));
    asm volatile ("invlpg (%eax)"); // invlpg is privileged! must be run in non-usermode
    asm volatile ("sti");
}



// vmm_allocatePage(pte_t *entry) - Allocate VMM pages
bool vmm_allocatePage(pte_t *entry) {
    // Allocate a free physical frame
    void *p = pmm_allocateBlock();
    if (!p) return false; // Failed to get the block

    // Map it to the page.
    pte_setframe(entry, (uint32_t)p);
    pte_addattrib(entry, PTE_PRESENT);

    return true;
}

// vmm_freePage() - Frees a page.
void vmm_freePage(pte_t *entry) {
    // Very simple - just free the memory block and set the PRESENT bit to 0.
    void *ptr = (void*)pte_getframe(*entry);
    if (ptr) pmm_freeBlock(ptr);

    pte_delattrib(entry, PTE_PRESENT);
}

// vmm_mapPage(void *physical_addr, void *virtual_addr) - Maps a page from the physical address to its virtual address
void vmm_mapPage(void *physical_addr, void *virtual_addr) {
    // Get page directory
    pagedirectory_t *pageDirectory = vmm_getCurrentDirectory();

    // Get the page table
    pde_t *entry = &pageDirectory->entries[PAGEDIR_INDEX((uint32_t)virtual_addr)];
    if ((*entry & PTE_PRESENT) != PTE_PRESENT) {
        serialPrintf("vmm_mapPage: entry not present, allocating it...\n");

        pagetable_t *table = (pagetable_t*)pmm_allocateBlock();
        if (!table) return; // failed to get the block

        // Clear the page table.
        memset(table, 0, sizeof(pagetable_t));

        // Create a new entry
        pde_t *e = &pageDirectory->entries[PAGEDIR_INDEX((uint32_t)virtual_addr)];

        // Map it in the table
        pde_addattrib(e, PDE_PRESENT);
        pde_addattrib(e, PDE_WRITABLE);
        pde_setframe(e, (uint32_t)table);
    }

    // Get the table
    pagetable_t *table = (pagetable_t*)VIRTUAL_TO_PHYS(entry);

    // Get the page.
    pte_t *page = &table->entries[PAGETBL_INDEX((uint32_t)virtual_addr)];

    // Map it in
    pte_setframe(page, (uint32_t)physical_addr);
    pte_addattrib(page, PTE_PRESENT);
}

// vmm_enablePaging() - Turns on paging
void vmm_enablePaging() {
    uint32_t cr0, cr4;

    asm volatile ("mov %%cr4, %0" : "=r"(cr4));
    cr4 = cr4 & 0xffffffef;
    asm volatile ("mov %0, %%cr4" :: "r"(cr4));

    asm volatile ("mov %%cr0, %0" : "=r"(cr0));
    cr0 = cr0 | 0x80000000;

    asm volatile ("mov %0, %%cr0" :: "r"(cr0));
    while (true) {
        
    }
}

// vmmInit() - Initialize the VMM.
void vmmInit() {
    // Allocate the default page table.
    pagetable_t *table = (pagetable_t*)pmm_allocateBlock();
    if (!table) return; // failed to get the block

    // Allocate 3gb page table
    pagetable_t *table2 = (pagetable_t*)pmm_allocateBlock();
    if (!table2) return; // failed to get the block

    // Clear the page table.
    memset(table, 0, sizeof(pagetable_t));

    // Identity map the first 4MB, since when paging is enabled, all addresses are made virtual.
    for (int i = 0, frame=0x0, virt=0x00000000; i < 1024; i++, frame += 4096, virt += 4096) {
        // Create a new page and change its frame.
        pte_t page = 0;
        pte_addattrib(&page, PTE_PRESENT);
        pte_setframe(&page, frame);

        // Add the above page to the page table.
        table2->entries[PAGETBL_INDEX(virt)] = page;
    }

    // Create the default page directory and clear it.
    pagedirectory_t *dir = (pagedirectory_t*)pmm_allocateBlock();
    if (!dir) return; // failed to get the block

    memset(dir, 0, sizeof(pagedirectory_t));

    // Now, since we identity mapped the first 4MB, we need to create a PDE for that (two for both tables).
    // The first PDE is for the first 4MB, the second is for the next, ...
    pde_t *entry = &dir->entries[PAGEDIR_INDEX(0xc0000000)];
    pde_addattrib(entry, PDE_PRESENT);
    pde_addattrib(entry, PDE_WRITABLE);
    pde_setframe(entry, (uint32_t)table);

    pde_t *entry2 = &dir->entries[PAGEDIR_INDEX(0x00000000)];
    pde_addattrib(entry2, PDE_PRESENT);
    pde_addattrib(entry2, PDE_WRITABLE);
    pde_setframe(entry2, (uint32_t)table2);

    // Set our ISR interrupt handler
    isrRegisterInterruptHandler(14, pageFault);

    // Store the current PDBR
    currentPDBR = (uint32_t)&dir->entries;

    // Switch to the page directory.
    vmm_switchDirectory(dir);

    // Enable paging!
    vmm_enablePaging();

    serialPrintf("vmmInit: Successfully initialized paging.\n");
}

Right after I set the PG bit in CR0 in vmm_enablePaging() (mov %0, %%cr0), qEMU crashes with a page fault exception (edited to be the actual 0xE exception):
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xe
    69: v=0e e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:000000000010ac04 pc=000000000010ac04 SP=0010:00000000005bef60 CR2=00000000005c28c0
EAX=80000011 EBX=00000400 ECX=005bee60 EDX=00135cda
ESI=003ff003 EDI=00002000 EBP=00000002 ESP=005bef60
EIP=0010ac04 EFL=00000286 [--S--P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 00000000 00000000 00000000
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0000 00000000 00000000 00000000
FS =0000 00000000 00000000 00000000
GS =0000 00000000 00000000 00000000
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =002b 006011a0 00001208 0000e900 DPL=3 TSS32-avl
GDT=     00601220 0000ffff
IDT=     005c27c0 00000700
CR0=80000011 CR2=005c28c0 CR3=00020000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000084 CCD=80000011 CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000

I know when a page fault occurs the CPU pushes an error code onto the stack, but I couldn't make sense of the register dump.
In the code I provided, I also hung the function right after to prevent things like printf() being the fault, but it did not do anything.
I disassembled the code with gdb at instruction pointer and saw that whatever function placed there would trigger it (IP = 0x0010ac04):
113 void vmm_enablePaging() {
114     uint32_t cr0, cr4;
115 
116     asm volatile ("mov %%cr4, %0" : "=r"(cr4));
   0x0010abf0 <+0>: 0f 20 e0    mov    %cr4,%eax

117     cr4 = cr4 & 0xffffffef;
118     asm volatile ("mov %0, %%cr4" :: "r"(cr4));
   0x0010abf3 <+3>: 83 e0 ef    and    $0xffffffef,%eax
   0x0010abf6 <+6>: 0f 22 e0    mov    %eax,%cr4

119 
120     asm volatile ("mov %%cr0, %0" : "=r"(cr0));
   0x0010abf9 <+9>: 0f 20 c0    mov    %cr0,%eax

121     cr0 = cr0 | 0x80000000;
122 
123     asm volatile ("mov %0, %%cr0" :: "r"(cr0));
   0x0010abfc <+12>:    0d 00 00 00 80  or     $0x80000000,%eax
   0x0010ac01 <+17>:    0f 22 c0    mov    %eax,%cr0

124     while (true) {
   0x0010ac04 <+20>:    eb fe   jmp    0x10ac04 <vmm_enablePaging+20>

I tried clearing the PSE bit but that didn't get anywhere. Also, CR3 is set to the page directory.
Thank you for your help!
Edit: Here are two other files that manage page directory entries and page table entries.
vmm_pde.c
// pde_addattrib(pde_t *entry, uint32_t attribute) - Add attribute
void pde_addattrib(pde_t *entry, uint32_t attribute) {
    *entry = *entry | attribute;
}

// pde_delattrib(pde_t *entry, uint32_t attribute) - Delete/clear attribute
void pde_delattrib(pde_t *entry, uint32_t attribute) {
    *entry = *entry & ~(attribute);
}

// pde_setframe(pde_t *entry, uint32_t physical_addr) - Set the PDE frame address
void pde_setframe(pde_t *entry, uint32_t physical_addr) {
    *entry = (*entry & ~PDE_FRAME) | physical_addr;
}

// pde_ispresent(pde_t entry) - Returns whether the PDE is present in memory
bool pde_ispresent(pde_t entry) {
    return entry & PDE_PRESENT; 
}

// pde_iswritable(pde_t entry) - Returns whether the PDE is writable
bool pde_iswritable(pde_t entry) {
    return entry & PDE_WRITABLE;
}

// pde_getframe(pde_t entry) - Returns the address of PDE_FRAME
uint32_t pde_getframe(pde_t entry) {
    return entry & PDE_FRAME;
}

// pde_isuser(pde_t entry) - Returns whether the PDE is usermode
bool pde_isuser(pde_t entry) {
    return entry & PDE_USER;
}

// pde_is4mb(pde_t entry) - Returns whether the PDE is 4MB pages
bool pde_is4mb(pde_t entry) {
    return entry & PDE_4MB;
}

vmm_pte.c
// pte_addattrib(pte_t *entry, uint32_t attribute) - Add an attribute to the PTE.
void pte_addattrib(pte_t *entry, uint32_t attribute) {
    *entry |= attribute;
}

// pte_delattrib(pte_t *entry, uint32_t attribute) - Delete an attribute from the PTE.
void pte_delattrib(pte_t *entry, uint32_t attribute) {
    *entry &= ~attribute;
}

// pte_setframe(pte_t *entry, uint32_t physical_addr) - Set the PTE frame.
void pte_setframe(pte_t *entry, uint32_t physical_addr) {
    *entry = (*entry & ~PTE_FRAME) | physical_addr;
}

// pte_ispresent(pte_t entry) - Returns whether the PTE is in memory or not.
bool pte_ispresent(pte_t entry) {
    return entry & PTE_PRESENT;
}

// pte_iswritable(pte_t entry) - Returns whether the PTE is writable.
bool pte_iswritable(pte_t entry) {
    return entry & PTE_WRITABLE;
}

// pte_getframe(pte_t entry) - Returns the address of the PTE frame.
uint32_t pte_getframe(pte_t entry) {
    return entry & PTE_FRAME;
}

Edit: After fixing the ISR code, Bochs throws an exception.
00542871884i[CPU0  ] CS.mode = 32 bit
00542871884i[CPU0  ] SS.mode = 32 bit
00542871884i[CPU0  ] EFER   = 0x00000000
00542871884i[CPU0  ] | EAX=e0000011  EBX=00000400  ECX=007ffe60  EDX=00135e4e
00542871884i[CPU0  ] | ESP=00420008  EBP=00000002  ESI=007ff003  EDI=00002000
00542871884i[CPU0  ] | IOPL=0 id vip vif ac vm RF nt of df if tf SF zf af PF cf
00542871884i[CPU0  ] | SEG sltr(index|ti|rpl)     base    limit G D
00542871884i[CPU0  ] |  CS:0008( 0001| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
00542871884i[CPU0  ] |  DS:0010( 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
00542871884i[CPU0  ] |  SS:0010( 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
00542871884i[CPU0  ] |  ES:0010( 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
00542871884i[CPU0  ] |  FS:0010( 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
00542871884i[CPU0  ] |  GS:0010( 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
00542871884i[CPU0  ] | EIP=00100202 (00100202)
00542871884i[CPU0  ] | CR0=0xe0000011 CR2=0x0041fffc
00542871884i[CPU0  ] | CR3=0x00020000 CR4=0x00000000
(0).[542871884] ??? (physical address not available)
00542871884e[CPU0  ] exception(): 3rd (14) exception with no resolution, shutdown status is 00h, resetting


Reposting suggestions from staging: (1) try Bochs as it has a better built-in debugger than QEMU.  (2) Try dumping your page tables after populating them, to make sure they contain what you intended.

The value in CR2 is mysterious.  It should be the faulting address, but it doesn't match EIP, and the faulting instruction doesn't perform any other memory access.

Unrelated, but your inline asm in vmm_flushTLBEntry is problematic.  You can't rely on eax keeping its value between two separate asm statements, and you aren't informing the compiler that it's overwritten.  I think (untested) you could replace the whole thing with asm volatile("cli ; invlpg (%0) ; sti" : : "r" (addr));

@NateEldredge I dumped the page tables and saw that the pages had proper frames and were being marked as present and writable.

Is it possible CR2 is that way because its the virtual address being stored? I'm not sure.

Your segments have a base of 0 so virtual addresses should equal linear.

Ah, that is true. I'm not sure what's going on with CR2 then. Potentially the issue - when dumping the page tables, I used functions from two other files that handled page directory entries and page table entries, and writable returned 2 instead of 1 or 0, but I don't know if that's the problem. They seem to be marked okay.

That doesn't make any sense, but impossible to know what it means without seeing the code.

I will attach the code.

I attached the two other files - I don't think they are bugged but can't be too sure.

Rather than just showing the double fault v=08 exception output in the QEMU output... can you show the v=0e (the actual page fault) dump just before it? The page fault v=0e dump will potentially tell you why it page faulted especially with the e=nnnn value.

Since it failed on the infinite loop I can only assume that an interrupt occurred during the loop that caused the page fault. Do you happen to have this on Github?

@MichaelPetch Yes, it is available at this repo. I just now pushed my local changes, so the code there is the exact code being used. I will also update the question to include that specific qEMU dump.

So v=0e (page fault) has e=0000 (the error code). e=0000 suggests that a read was done in supervisor mode to a page that wasn't present while accessing memory @ 005c28c0. Given that this apparently happened in an infinite loop I assume that an interrupt caused the issue. Was there an interrupt just before this? I'll take a look at your repo when I have a chance.

I don't believe so. I looked at the assembly and didn't see anything that was an interrupt in vmmInit.

I misread what you meant when referring to  0x0010ac04 <+20>:    eb fe   jmp    0x10ac04 <vmm_enablePaging+20> . I thought that was the instruction it was failing on. TO find the exact instruction you should use objdump -Dx on the kernel ELF file to find out what instruction at CS:EIP it is failing at.

@MichaelPetch I'm quite sure that IS the instruction it's failing on, since EIP is 0x0010ac04, and that instruction is to just infinite loop.

Your EFLAGS (EFL=286) is in Hex and that has the Interrupt Flag enabled (bit 9). It isn't the JMP instruction that is failing. It is an interrupt coming in that ultimately causes the page fault. Reviewing the log, just before the v=0e is a v=20 dump and that is the timer at the same instruction.

@MichaelPetch Wow, I didn't actually notice that! How should I go about fixing it? Is it a bug in my IDT (I wouldn't be surprised)?

In the QEMU monitor info mem command shows this mapping 0000000000000000-0000000000400000 0000000000400000 -rw
00000000c0000000-00000000c0400000 0000000000400000 -rw . The address trying to be read is 005c28c0 which is not in a mapped region (not present) so it page faults. It appears your mapping doesn't cover the entire memory space that your kernel is actually using. I noticed your stack is in that region too. You mentioned if you added a function call in that loop it would fail. Probably because the stack isn't mapped either.

It seems that all your data structures like GDT, IDT, and your TSS are all in memory that isn't mapped. The address in CR2=005c28c0 . Your IDT starts at 5c27c0. Each IDT entry is 8 bytes so CR2 points at the memory address in your IDT where interrupt 0x20 resides (0x20*8+5c27c0=5c28c0=CR2). So I can conclude that you haven't mapped your entire kernel memory in properly - the IDT is at a virtual memory address that isn't present so it fails there,

@MichaelPetch I added another identity mapping for mapping frames 0x400000-0x800000 and now I'm getting further - Paging does enable successfully and returns to the original function (I removed the while true) but crashes shortly after vmmInit completes.

qEMU monitor shows that 0000000000000000-0000000000800000 0000000000800000 -rw is being mapped but it crashes shortly after returning back to the kernel.

I recommend this. Run QEMU with -d int -no-reboot -no-shutdown that way when a triple fault occurs QEMU neither reboots or shutsdown. You can then look at the log to find out what instruction it fails at. You can dump everything in your kernel with objdump -Dx out/kernel/kernel.elf >dump.txt where the dump.txt file can tell you what machine instruction is at CS:EIP that failed. You can also click on your OS'es Window and click Control-Alt-2 to switch to the QEMU monitor to issue commands to further help debugging.

You can always update your Github so I can look at your change.

@MichaelPetch My apologies for the later reply, I updated the GitHub with my new code. I'm trying to use qEMU but not really getting all that far

I ran qEMU on the system and it did not crash, but when I got to the end I ran the info mem command and returned a bunch of random values that I'm not sure. It looks as though this may be the default memory mappings.

Fixed the above and pushed new changes.

@MichaelPetch I'm now getting a general protection fault after another interrupt.

The GPF's IP is instruction 10af5b, which does not show when objdump -Dx is run. The closest instruction is 10af5a, which pushes 0x135d40 onto the stack. Right after, serialPrintf is called.

I am very confused as the 0xD exception is apparently setting the error code 0xFFFC, indicating a problem with the LDT (which I don't have), in the last index.

In my testing here things go fine until I press a few keys and then I eventually end up with EIP being 0xffffffff (-1) and it then page faults. I haven't investigated why that happened, but letting you know I don't see a GPF with the current code.

@MichaelPetch That's certainly strange - mine is reporting a 0xD GPF with e=fffc. I will try cloning the repo and building from scratch when I get back from my job. Thank you for all your help!

I'll update you on how it goes.

@MichaelPetch I had enough time to re-clone the github and run it - I am still getting a GPF. I would suggest either updating the repo or running make clean and recompiling - very odd behavior!

I can't produce that particular behaviour here (yes, I have the latest from your repo and I did start with make clean). That's not entirely unexpected. It could be a timing related issue or it might be different because of different code generation between your environment and mine. Different version of compilers can generate different code. When I get a chance I'll try to find what causes things to go wrong here and it might relate to the failures you are seeing.

Thank you, this really helps me out. I've been struggling for a while - I'll try and fix my environment to see if that might be the problem.

I don't think there is a problem with your environment. Compilers output different code and nothing you can do about that. Anyway, I did discover a couple of things that are a problem. Take a look at the code in isrCommonStub and irqCommonStub after you call the handlers. In isrCommonStub you pop ds and pop es. This causes stack issues since that's not what is pushed. Replace that with pop ebx mov ds, bx mov es, bx mov fs, bx mov gs, bx. In irqCommonStub you do pop ebx which is fine but then you use ax to restore the segment registers when it should be bx

There are still more issues to fix as this only solved one of my problems and a new one appeared. I'll look later when I have time.

@MichaelPetch Done, uploaded the changes. Now it's just halting, but there is no more exception

This also patched bochs so I loaded up GDB and looked into it - bochs is hanging itself on ISR7, at 100200 on push byte 0.

Opened up bochs debugger, it appears that a page is not present. CR2 is something trying to read 0x0041FFFC, which is supposed to be mapped, quite strange. Instruction is 1001d7

I'll update the post with the bochs error.

Is it possible that with your Serial Logging enabling code that you turn on interrupts before you set up the APIC? I found it odd that there is a v=06 that doesn't appear to be exception #UD (Invalid opcode) but may actually be IRQ6 instead?

@MichaelPetch I'm not exactly sure. serialinit seems to just be outportb() which is just outb instructions.

@MichaelPetch I added serialTestPassed = false and returned on the seiralInit function, which did disable output, but no further sadly.

No worries - thank you for devoting so much already.

Before it fails the memory map looks like this: 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000003fffff -> 0x000000400000-0x0000007fffff
0x0000000000400000-0x00000000007fffff -> 0x000000000000-0x0000003fffff
0x0000000000800000-0x0000000000bfffff -> 0x000000800000-0x000000bfffff . You aren't mapping one to one here? The physical addresses seem to be out of order. My guess is you have set this up incorrectly and then when paging is enabled the linear address is being mapped to the wrong physical addresses and as a result the code for interrupts is mapped to wrong place.

@MichaelPetch I didn't notice that - any idea what changed? It was good before right?

It appears you reversed these: pde_setframe(entry, (uint32_t)table2); should be pde_setframe(entry, (uint32_t)table); and pde_setframe(entry2, (uint32_t)table); should be pde_setframe(entry2, (uint32_t)table2);. After that things appear to fail in vbeGetInfo(); for other reasons.

@MichaelPetch Fixed that issue. vbeGetInfo() calls bios32 which uses addresses that should be paged in - 0x4F00 and 0x7E00.

Somehow paging gets corrupted in vbegetinfo. In QEMU I see this on the page fault: CR0=80000011 CR2=00007c0c CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000 Notice that CR3=0. Something changed CR3 and it is pointing at garbage at the bottom of memory. Because the page structure is effectively garbage there is a fault when trying to access  memory that the CPU thinks is now not present. Maybe your BIOS related code didn't disable paging when entering real mode?

@MichaelPetch I don't think it even tried - do I just unset the PG bit or how should I go about that?

So first off obviously you can't change CR3 until after you disable paging. Move the 3 instructions that change CR3 and saves the old value to  right after label __real_mode_16:. You will have to disable paging when you turn off protected mode. So you can change the code that disabled protected mode to something like mov eax, cr0 and eax,  ~0x80000001 mov cr0, eax

@MichaelPetch Went ahead and added those instructions to the start of __real_mode_116:use16 but I'm still getting a page fault - just disabling it though for now, not re-enabling so maybe that's why

@NateEldredge: inline asm for cli ; invlpg (%0) definitely should have a "memory" clobber; you don't want the compiler reordering memory accesses across it, to *addr or anywhere else.  (You could let the compiler pick the addressing mode with "m" (*addr) and using %0 instead of (%0), but you'd still want a memory clobber since it affects the whole page.  And you don't want memory reordering wrt. CLI either.)

@MichaelPetch I added some code to disable paging, save CR3 to EBX and zero it, then restore paging and CR3, but now I'm getting a hang on the 0x6 instruction after disabling paging.

*0x6 exception, invalid opcode
I pushed the changes to the GitHub. Bochs complains about a ton of invalid port writes and then dies due to IO write (0x01F0) current command is a1h

If I continue, VBE complains about a write to an unsupported register at 0x417.

Your code is experiencing some strange behaviour. I haven't looked at it fully. While trying to clean something up I stumbled on something In memset - you have for (; n != 0; n--) temp[n] = c; . I think that is a bug and should be for (; n != 0; n--) temp[n-1] = c; . It seems to me you are setting memory offset by 1 which can lead to unwanted corruption (the first byte beyond the memory region specified is set and the first byte is not set)

Note: I discovered the memset bug when I looked at the QEMU output and saw IDT=     008037c0 00000700 . Looking at the code the limit 700 should have been 7ff. I thought it was suspicious and I used BOCHS to see what function/instruction was clobbering the size field. That was when I saw what memset was doing. Using temp[n-1] resolved that problem with the IDT but could be causing other unwanted or undefined behaviour.

There's a whole lot of issues and what I'm going to tell you won't fix everything. It just fixes some of the issues but still fails. In your gdtInit you will need to change to using gdtPtr.limit = sizeof(gdtEntries)-1; gdtPtr.base = (uint32_t)&gdtEntries;. You were hard coding limit to 0xfff and that's too big for BIOS.ASM to handle (it has memory for 64 bytes or 8 GDT entries). I recommend doing something similar in your idtInit . In bios.asm you have a bug in your disable paging. It should be mov eax, cr0 and eax, DISABLE_PAGING mov cr0, eax

In BIOS.ASM before doing the ret you do an sti there. Remove that. The fellow you copied that code from has a bug. You can't enable interrupts until the IDT is reloaded in your bios32_call function. Enabling them before that point runs the risk of an interrupt coming in without a proper IDT! Even if you do all the things I have mentioned it will still crash. There are some stack related issues in the real mode code that I haven't worked through yet.

I've made a variety of changes and improved the code of the original bios32_call. I used the last version of the code you put away on July 2nd (commit https://github.com/sasdallas/reduceOS/tree/2931594c7eb1d3ffceb6c50e7b5eb599363c2cca ) . I've created a git patch called SO78689448-patch1.diff for that version and it can be found here https://pastebin.com/HumECNQg . You should be able to place the diff file in the main directory and apply it with git apply --reject --whitespace=fix SO78689448-patch1.diff

When I run it here on QEMU and BOCHS it will run but throws page faults when switching buffers. What I didn't fix is that the framebuffer is not mapped into virtual memory so when you attempt to switch buffers it will fail. You will have to map the video memory to resolve that problem. I have left that as an exercise for you. Note: the framebuffer is returned by the BIOS call you make and in BOCHS and QEMU the address is usually 0xfd000000 but can vary depending on hardware. You will notice that CR2=fd000000 when it page faults

@MichaelPetch Wow, you have been a godsend helping me through this. I genuinely can't thank you enough - this is amazing work! The VMM now initializes properly, but now for some reason the isrIRQHandler isn't being called, at all. Everything else works perfectly though, and I did add vmm_allocateRegion to allocate the framebuffer. I now just need to fix the ISR keyboard handler.

I ran BOCHS and breakpointed after VBE initialization. I then ran info idt 32 to get the KB interrupt, and it returned IDT[0x20]=32-Bit Interrupt Gate target=0x0008:0x00100312, DPL=0. I tried doing a VB on that address, but it was never called.

Stepping through instructions also doesn't show anything - it just repeats 3 instructions.

As well as that, neither isrExceptionHandler() nor isrIRQHandler() are being called, and I don't even think the assembly is being called.

I'll look at it later when I have a chance. It appears it is in an infinite loop looking for the newline character but no new interrupts are coming in (but the interrupt flag is enabled). I haven't looked at the reason but make sure you are sending EOI properly after handling external interrupts and when you get a keyboard interrupt make sure you get a single character at a time for each interrupt.

EOI could be an issue, I remember fiddling with that - I'll look at it when I get home.

I found a few problems. All involve EOI in one way or another.  interruptCompleted should be if (intNo >= 40) outportb(0xA0, 0x20); outportb(0x20, 0x20); .  In isrIRQHandler it should be interruptCompleted(reg->int_no); but you have interruptCompleted(reg->int_no); . Lastly and this is a temporary fix for a more complicated issue involving IRQs/EOI in real mode. In BIOS.ASM comment out the sti . Enabling interrupts in real mode is problematic since the IRQs have been remapped and the wrong real mode handlers are being called and as a result EOIs are not properly handled.

You can handle external interrupts in real mode but one has to remap the PICs back to their original real mode configuration and then change them back to the protected mode configuration upon returning from real mode. That way the interrupts will be properly directed to the right real mode handlers and in turn EOIs are properly handled. If I get a hance later today I'll see if I can resolve that for you IF you really need to use external interrupts. VBE/VESA BIOS called don't rely on external interrupts  to run so can be done with the interrupts off.

I made a typo earlier. I meant you have interruptCompleted(reg->err_code); and it should have been interruptCompleted(reg->int_no);

@MichaelPetch Everything seems to be working perfectly - thank you for your help!!! Would you mind putting some of the important bits in an answer that I can accept?

Don't worry about resolving external interrupts - I'll be fine without them, and I've already bothered you enough :)

Not sure you noticed but on Github I made a couple of reports of bugs related to using uninitialized pointers that write all over the bottom of memory at 0x00000000 and issues with your itoa function.

@MichaelPetch Will take a look soon

@MichaelPetch I went ahead and replied to the issues - it's just that we're in a bit of an unstable state with kmalloc, as always haha
